# Check if PFObject is nil

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I want to check if a `PFObject` is nil

I retrieve the object

```
var userLibrary: PFObject?

func getUserLibrary(user: PFUser) {
    self.libraryQuery = PFQuery(className: "Library")
    self.libraryQuery?.whereKey("owner", equalTo: user)

    self.libraryQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if objects!.count > 0 {
                self.userLibrary = objects![0]
            } else {
                print(self.userLibrary)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

The last line with the print statement prints out `nil`.

However when I check :

```
if userLibrary != nil {
}
```

Xcode tells me

`Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'PFObject' and 'NilLiteralConvertible'`

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that this will work, but did you try.

```
if let lib = userLibrary {
     //do whatever
}
```

Let me know.

---

Also, if you are just using the first object of your query. It would better to use `getFirstObjectInBackground`